# How to show shipping method only for lease type of product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to to show shipping method on the checkout page in woocommerce for only lease type of product.

In my product lease is the category of the product ..
can any one help me to resolve this problem ... to hide shipping check box for all type of product not for lease type product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dd_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_all_shipping_when_cat' , 10, 2 );

function hide_all_shipping_when_cat(){

if(is_product_category( 'oranges' )){

unset( $rates['free_shipping'] );

// Unset all shipping methods you want with their names

}

}

try this
```